# Where are my System.Management.* classes?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

I just installed Visual Studio 2010 with .NET Framework 4.0 and C# and I can't find anything under the `System.Management` namespace except for `System.Management.Instrumentation`. All the online documentation at MSDN about WMI keeps telling me that I have to use classes such as `System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher` or `System.Management.ManagementScope` but I don't see those classes.

What happened to those classes and how can I access them?

Comment: Maybe check the references in your project. It could be it resides in one that is'nt added to your project.

Comment: Are you referencing the System.Management.dll?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

**You need to [add a reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky(v=VS.100).aspx) to `System.Management.dll` to your project.**

You can see `System.Management.Instrumentation` without adding a reference to `System.Management.dll` because it is included in a different library (`System.Core.dll`, which is included as a reference automatically), but you cannot access the other types contained by that namespace without explicitly adding a reference to the `System.Management.dll` library.

Comment: I found this link more useful than the one above for adding references. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-add-or-remove-references-by-using-the-reference-manager?view=vs-2017

Answer (score 6):

If you're using VS 2010, switch the project to .Net 4.0. Then click on Add References, you will now see System.Management in the list (and not only System.Management.Instrumentation). You can now use the System.Management classes.

I just had the same problem, and that fixed it!

Answer (score 6):

I have netcore and net471 project.

I just downloaded the **System.Management** as official Microsoft nuget plugin.

Answer (score 2):

Have you added a reference to `System.Management`?

This may be due to having set the framework target to "Client Profile". Try switching to the normal "4.0 Framework".

Comment: `System.Management.dll` and `System.Management.Instrumentation.dll` are both included in the Client Profile. You shouldn't have to target the full framework.

Answer (score 1):

Have you added a reference to `System.Management.dll` in your project?

Answer (score 1):

Add a reference to the `System.Management.dll` assembly. Both the `System.Management.ManagementObjectSearcher` and the `System.Management.ManagementScope` types are present in this assembly.

The reason you see the other types is because many types from the namespace `System.Management.Instrumentation` are present in `System.Core.dll`, which is normally automatically included by Visual Studio as a project reference.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a reference to System.Management.dll I think.

Answer (score 0):

Find it on your computer > System.Management.dll

Find the .NetFrameWork version that fits your project.

Find the .NetFramework version in the folder name at the end of the search.

Copy the file.

Discard it in the "Bin" folder in your project.

Right click on the references in your project.

Click Add Reference.

Select the file (Project Root > Bin > System.Management.dll).

Project Clean and build.