# Missing reference to System.Diagnostics.Process

Tags: c#, .net, windows, .net-4.5

I have a app that I am building to shut down a computer

I tried using 
     using System.Management;
but it tells me to add a reference,  No such thing in the add reference list
I tried using this code but the proccess has a red squigly

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("Shutdown", "-s -t 10");
```

Any ideas on how to shut down?

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4193883/where-are-my-system-management-classes

Comment: I cannot find the System.Management.dll ? how do i install it ?

Comment: Are you targeting .net Framework 4 or client profile?

Comment: Your code above should work.  The only reason I could think it has the squiggly is if you do not have a reference to System.dll where Process is defined.

Comment: You say "red squiggly," but what error does that represent?  There will be a compiler error when you build...

Comment: What kind of shutdown do you want? A user cancelable countdown, or a plain shutdown?

Answer (score 1):

There's one simple explanation for a mystifying problem like this: you are using the Portable Class Libraries or have selected the ".NET for Metro style apps" platform target.  Which does not permit using the Process class, Metro apps operate in a sandbox that disables many standard .NET features.  Starting another process or shutting down the OS is *not* permitted, only the user can do that.

You'll have to give up on Metro if this is important to you, your app needs to run as a desktop app.  And won't run on a slate that boots Win8.

Comment: And this is why today we dont see metro apps

Answer (score 0):

I ended up

1. upgrading to the latest Visual Studio 2015 SP3,
2. running Scott Smith's upgrade command using powershell,

   ```
   powershell dnvm upgrade -r coreclr
   ```

   https://stackoverflow.com/a/34013990/80772
3. creating a console project anew from Visual Studio.

After adding more packages required to resolve the standard classes I observed this global.json,

```
{
  "projects": [ "src", "test" ],
  "sdk": {
    "version": "1.0.0-preview2-003131"
  }
}
```

and this project.json,

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "buildOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.NETCore.App": {
      "type": "platform",
      "version": "1.0.1"
    },
    "system.diagnostics.textwritertracelistener": "4.0.0-beta-23123",
    "System.Diagnostics.TraceSource": "4.0.0",
    "System.IO": "4.1.0"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "netcoreapp1.0": {
      "imports": "dnxcore50"
    }
  }
}
```