# Why is there no Process class in my System.Diagnostics namespace?

Tags: c#, namespaces

I'm currently using  `C# Express`. It does have a `system.dll 4.2` and I added this reference. However,  there are lots of stuff missing in it; such as the `Process class` in the `System.Diagnostics namespace`.

BTW, another question: each `dll` file has some `namespace` and the `System.Diagnostics` namespace is declared in the `system.dll file`. Am I right about that?
So what if I want to use the process class?

thanks

Comment: I am not following...  I use C# Express and adding a reference to `System.Diagnostics`, am able to access the `Process class` just fine.  Can you post some code?

Comment: What project type are you creating? Sounds like one that doesn't support `Process` (Windows Store apps).

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11845828/missing-reference-to-system-diagnostics-process

Comment: @keyboardP I'm building a netduino plus project. it's a device board. is it because that its not win store app?

Comment: @henryyao - No, Win Store apps don't have access to `Process` and `Netduino` doesn't either. I'm not familiar with it but it seems to be based on the `.NET Micro Framework` which doesn't have support for the `Process` class.

Comment: @keyboardP I think u r right. It is a .net micro framwork based project. So is there another a way out or there is no way...

Comment: @henryyao Unfortunately I doubt it'd be as easy as using the `Process` class. What do you need to do?

Comment: @keyboardP I need to see the status of my threads in this process.

Comment: @henryyao - You could try using the [System.Threading](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee436582.aspx) namespace. It has a [Thread](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee436590.aspx) class with status properties.

Comment: Good grief, all of this could have been so much easier if you had specified this in the question. And the comment block is not a place to ask additional questions. Please post another, and be more specific the next time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Netduino uses the [.NET Micro Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee435793.aspx) which doesn't support the `Process` class.

Answer (score 1):

Try uninstalling and re-installing VCS excpress.  It seems I remember seeing a similar issue somewhere (I know, really specific), that this solved that problem.

The other thing might be to check the target framework of your project, and make sure it's not using Metro or compact or anything of the sort.

Edit: quick search led me to this: [Missing reference to System.Diagnostics.Process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11845828/missing-reference-to-system-diagnostics-process)