# Unable to use System.Net.Utilities with DNX 4.5.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mono, dnx

first post and complete C#, DNX, ASP.net noob so please be nice.

I'm having trouble building my ASP.net 5.0 project using DNX 4.5.1. My project.json file contains the following:

```
  {
  "version": "1.0.0-*",
  "compilationOptions": {
    "emitEntryPoint": true
  },
  "tooling": {
    "defaultNamespace": "PingTest1"
  },

  "dependencies": {
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Diagnostics": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.IISPlatformHandler": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.TagHelpers": "6.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.StaticFiles": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.AspNet.Tooling.Razor": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.FileProviderExtensions" : "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Debug": "1.0.0-rc1-final",
    "System.Net.NetworkInformation": "4.1.0-beta-23516",
    "System.Net.Utilities": "4.0.0-beta-23516"
  },

  "commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel"
  },

  "frameworks": {
    "dnx451": {},
    "dnxcore50": {}
  },

  "exclude": [
    "wwwroot",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components"
  ],
  "publishExclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "**.xproj",
    "**.user",
    "**.vspscc"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "prepublish": [
      "npm install",
      "bower install",
      "gulp clean",
      "gulp min"
    ]
  }
}
```

And "dnu restore" installs everything as it should. However when I run "dnu build", I get these two errors:

```
error NU1002: The dependency System.Net.Utilities 4.0.0-beta-23516 in project PingTest1 does not support framework DNX,Version=v4.5.1.

DNXCore,Version=v5.0 error CS1061: 'Ping' does not contain a definition for 'Send' and no extension method 'Send' accepting a first argument of type 'Ping' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Being a complete noob, I have no idea how to correct this and googling doesn't find any answers. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

My complete source code can be found here: https://github.com/00101010b/PingTest1

Comment: If anyone finds this as a problem more recently, the `System.Net.Utilities` package was renamed `System.Net.Ping`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to remove the following line from project.json file:

```
"dnx451": {},
```

And run the following commands in order from Terminal.app:

```
dnvm upgrade -r coreclr
dnu restore
dnu build
```

And finally I replaced some of my code to use Ping().SendPingAsync().

This fixed the build issue. However, I still have issues with pinging IP addresses... I will post a new thread about it shortly.

Many thanks.