Retrieving the network speed in Visual Basic
I'm coding in Visual Studio 2019.
The program that I'm making will run on PC's with multiple network connections.
It must get the names of the ports, their mac addresses, and their IP addresses.
So far it goes well.
Now I want to get the network speed of these ports.
I found this code:
Sub Main()
    Try
        ' Create a management object searcher to query network adapters
        Dim searcher As New ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapter WHERE NetEnabled = True")

        ' Iterate through each network adapter found
        For Each adapter As ManagementObject In searcher.Get()
            ' Get the name and speed of the network adapter
            Dim adapterName As String = adapter("Name").ToString()
            Dim adapterSpeed As ULong = CType(adapter("Speed"), ULong)

            ' Convert speed to Mbps
            Dim speedMbps As Double = adapterSpeed / 1000000

            ' Output the adapter name and speed
            Console.WriteLine("Adapter: " & adapterName)
            Console.WriteLine("Speed: " & speedMbps & " Mbps")
            Console.WriteLine("------------------------------")
        Next
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine("Error: " & ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub

Added Imports System.Management
But when compiling I get the following messages:

Type ManagementObjectSearcher is not defined
Type ManagementObject is not defined

Where can I find the definition of those?

See the accepted answer in this question and look at the link it provides for how to do it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4193883/where-are-my-system-management-classes

This question is similar to: Where are my System.Management.* classes?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
